# CKEditor: How to manually trigger ACF(Advanced Content Filter)

Tags: ckeditor

With older version of CKEditor, I use following code to manually trigger Advanced Content Filter before submitting the content to server, but this stopped working for Version 4.4. I wonder is there a way to manually trigger the ACF and/or other kinds of content validation in CKEditor?

```
editor.setData(editor.getData(););
```

Comment: I'm curious; how does non-ACF'd data get into the editor to begin with?

Comment: It began with dirty data when there wasn't ACF in pre-4.1 version.

Comment: But when you load that data into CKEditor, doesn't ACF filter it then?

Comment: @Nenotlep Yes, that's the problem, we would lost data, so we want to manually trigger the ACF to see where the changes CKEditor might make before submit.

Comment: That does sound a little complicated. I think storing the values outside CKEditor and comparing them before submit might be the most sure thing. If you want to see if ACF fires at all, there is the `dataFiltered` event you can follow. http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-dataFiltered

Comment: I don't understand the problem. So you have an editor which has ACF disabled, am I right? Because otherwise disallowed content would not get into editor in the first place. So I don't believe that `editor.setData(editor.getData())` could ever work (and BTW. nothing  changed in 4.4). Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution actually worked for me! To be more precise, I used `CKEDITOR.instances['instance_name'].setData( CKEDITOR.instances['instance_name'].getData() )` and it worked!

To other people asking: this can be very useful even if you have ACF turned ON; in our app there's a number of situations that we manipulate the DOM inside CKEditor directly using jQuery for some very custom features we have (we actually create some UI inside the editor area), but we don't want that forbidden HTML going to the server and this solution works perfectly.

(Of course we always sanitize on the server as well)

Answer (score 0):

For us this

`CKEDITOR.instances['instance_name'].setData( CKEDITOR.instances['instance_name'].getData() )`

didn't work, but getting the data with 1 in the arguments worked.

`CKEDITOR.instances['instance_name'].setData( CKEDITOR.instances['instance_name'].getData(1) )`

Answer (score 0):

SetData(getData) did not work for me (using Version 4.14.1), anyhow, I managed to set all editors to WYSIWYG-mode and update before submit.
This way, ACF is always applied on save/submit, even when User submits while in source-mode:

```
// listener for mode change 
CKEDITOR.instances[instanceKey].on('mode', function(e) {
    var submitListener = function(){
        // set ckeditor to WYSIWYG-mode and update textarea
        CKEDITOR.instances[instanceKey].execCommand('source','wysiwyg');
        CKEDITOR.instances[instanceKey].updateElement();
        return true;
    }

    if( e.editor.mode == 'wysiwyg' ){
        // update textarea and disable submit handler
        CKEDITOR.instances[instanceKey].updateElement();
        document.querySelector(instanceKey).closest('form').removeEventListener('submit', submitListener);
    }

    if ( e.editor.mode == 'source' ) {
        // on submit, switch all editors back to wysiwyg and update, so ACF is always applied.
        document.querySelector(instanceKey).closest('form').addEventListener('submit', submitListener);
    }
}, null, instanceKey);
```